# Price Prediction via Neural Network (Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I am trying to do call price prediction my data set looks something like this

```
call_category_id,duration,Number 1,Number 2,price
9,24,77348,70000,0.01
9,144,77348,70000,0.08
9,138,77348,70000,0.08
9,12,77348,70000,0.01
```

The dialled number is split into two numbers(number 1, number 2) as i think it will improve prediction result. Usually first few digits of call dictate price per minute.

My model look something like this:

```py
def get_model():
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(40,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform',
              input_shape=(4,)),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(36,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform'),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(32,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform'),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(28,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform'),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(24,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform'),
        Dense(32,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform'),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(20,
              activation='relu',
              kernel_initializer='uniform'),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Dense(1, activation='linear'),
    ])
    c_optimizers = optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(optimizer=c_optimizers,
                  loss='mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

```py
model.fit(     x_train,     y_train,     batch_size=1024,     epochs=1000,     validation_data=(x_test, y_test),     shuffle=True,     callbacks=[tensor_board])
```

However the challenge is accuracy never improves it stuck at 19.6%.

```
39879/39879 [==============================] - 0s 5us/step - loss: 0.1646 - acc: 0.1969 - val_loss: 0.1003 - val_acc: 0.2065
```

Comment: Where is epochs? And, Is that data is real? Every rows have same number1 and number2.

Comment: hi i even run this for 100 k epochs same result. I removed the dialled number(Its is client data) -- i added the model.fit to the answer